# How to check is webpage is static or dynamic

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm doing some web scraping and using Jsoup to parse html files and my understanding is that Jsoup doesn't work well with dynamic web pages. Is there a way to check if a web page is dynamic so that I don't bother attempting to parse it using Jsoup?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Not really. You need to check case by case

Explanation:
Today's websites are full of ajax calls. Many are loading important data, others are only maginally interesting when you scrape a site's content. Many very modern sites even do both, they send  complete rendered page to the client where it gets transformed to a web-app (keyword isomorphic rendering)

So you need to check the site in question case by case. It is not that hard though. just fire up Curl and see if you get the content you need. If not, it is often also not that hard to understand the structure and parameters of the ajax calls. If you are doing this, then you often get even dynamic content fine with only Jsoup.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful

Answer (score -1):

You cannot be sure 100% that a website is `dynamic` or `static`, cause there are ways to hide the clues that show a website is `dynamic`. but you can check on a limited number of **HTTP response headers** to test whether its dynamic or static :

`Cookie` : **An HTTP cookie previously sent by the server with Set-Cookie**

`X-Csrf-Token` : **Used to prevent cross-site request forgery. Alternative header names are: X-CSRFToken and X-XSRF-TOKEN**

`X-Powered-By` : **specifies the technology (e.g. ASP.NET, PHP, JBoss) supporting the web application (version details are often in X-Runtime, X-Version, or X-AspNet-Version)**

These are 3 HTTP headers that a server scripting is involved with to generate(as far as I know)

Also chances are that a webpage with form related elements should have a server side mechanism to process form data.

Comment: Don't know. My answer also got some down-votes, although it is now in the positive range. Maybe someone who hates scraping or just a destructive mind at work. I gave you +1 since it sheds light on the question in another angle than my answer.

Comment: I downvoted your answer since it does not really answer the question. How exactly headers you mentioned help figuring out whether website is using Ajax eg?